# How to perform keyboard shortcut in VB

Tags: vb.net, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, onkeypress

I would like to know if it's possible, and if so how, to use VB.NET to automate the input of a keyboard shortcut.

In the application i am developing, it receives email as a outlook addin and runs various checks and if those checks are positive it inserts information about the message into the database.

But i want to be able to tell it that when the subject = "Keyword" to perform <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> for, essentially a prank.

However I can't find anything on this anywhere, all i find is "Custom Short-cuts In VB.NET" and stuff about the KeyDown, KeyUp and KeyPress events.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do such a thing would be to use the `SendKeys` method.  Untested I think <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> would look like:

```
SendKeys.Send("+(^{UP})")
```

[MSDN SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx?cs-lang=vb)